# How to know which lines in Node.JS code are involved when a "double callback" happens?

Tags: node.js, callback

In one of our complex Node JS program a "double callback" happens sometimes.
We would like to identify on which line(s) callback function is called twice ?

Is there a way to log those lines.
For now we only have one log entry "double callback!" which doesn't help us a lot.

Comment: What exactly is generating that "double callback!" log entry? If you can modify that code, you can use `console.trace('double callback')` to also log a stack trace which may identify where it's being called from.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought it was in Node.JS basis but it is in a library : superagent.
I'm on an old version. I'm going to upgrade and I'll see.